# Getting error when executing a PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I created a PDO object and an `INSERT INTO` query using array parameters, like so:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cluster', 'root', '');
if(!$pdo) {
    throw new PDOException("Failed connection!");
}

$qry = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO visitors_table(visitor_ip, visitor_browser,  visitor_hour,  visitor_minute,  visitor_day,  visitor_month,  visitor_year,  visitor_refferer,  visitor_page) "
    . "VALUES (:visitor_ip, :visitor_browser, :visitor_hour, :visitor_minute, :visitor_day, :visitor_month, :visitor:year, :visitor_refferer, :visitor_page)");

$arg = array(
    'visitor_ip' => $guest_ip,
    'visitor_browser' => $guest_browser,
    'visitor_hour' => date('H'),
    'visitor_minute' => date('i'),
    'visitor_day' => date('D'),
    'visitor_month' => date('M'),
    'visitor_year' => date('Y'),
    'visitor_refferer' => '',
    'visitor_page' => ''
);
```

But if I do

```
<?php if($qry->execute($arg) > 0): ?>
    Successful input!
<?php else: ?>
    Unsuccessful input!
<?php endif; ?>
```

I get the following response:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cluster\index.php on line 47
>   Unsuccessful input!

I tried to find the 'missing parameter', but everything just seams in order to me... Did I go blind and miss something obvious or is there something else to it?

**Side question:** For PHP programmers, is this the kind of indenting and naming you'd find readable and easy to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
$qry = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO visitors_table(visitor_ip, visitor_browser, 
  visitor_hour,  visitor_minute,  visitor_day,  visitor_month,  visitor_year,
   visitor_refferer,  visitor_page) "
. "VALUES (:visitor_ip, :visitor_browser, :visitor_hour, :visitor_minute, :visitor_day,
   :visitor_month, :visitor_year, :visitor_refferer, :visitor_page)");
                           ^here
```

Comment: Oh, wow.. the little things just kill you... Many likes to you sir and your snipy eyes!